# Is it possible to set an attribute's default value to a other attribute's value in XSD?

Tags: xml, xsd, xml-attribute

Suppose I have an XML like this:

```
<foo ...>
   <bar a="s1" b="s2" />
   <bar a="s3" />
</foo>
```

What I'd like is to define in the XSD is that the default value of attribute `b` should be the value of attribute `a`. Is that possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer: no.

Medium answer, according to "XML Schema Part 1: Structures Second Edition", section "3.2.1 The Attribute Declaration Schema Component": "*default* specifies that the attribute is to appear unconditionally in the ·post-schema-validation infoset·, with the supplied value used whenever the attribute is not actually present"

Long and practical answer: the key is "post-schema-validation infoset". So ask yourself what you need the schema document for?

- if you need it to validate incoming XML documents, then just use `use="required"` for attribute `b`
- if you need it to build objects (e.g., using some (un)marshalling technologies such as Java's JAXB or .NET's `XmlSerializer`) then you must explicitely add some post-processing which satisifies this "post-schema-validation-infoset" term - you should detect if the value of `b` wasn't set and set it yourself - that's your *business requirement*
- if you need to communicate your intent (*I/my app will treat empty `b` as having the same value as `a`) add documentation. XML Schema doesn't have such concept. Using extrapolation - that would be the same requirement as "the value of `b` will be the current USD/EUR ratio" - it's just computed value

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and for the great and detailed answer.